# variable container with jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, var

I am look for a way to use a variable with jquery.

I am grabbing the src attribbute from a hyperlink.

But i then want to append it to the hyerlink for jw player.

```
 '640','467','9');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
so.addVariable('file','I need the href attribute to go in here');
so.write('mediaspace');
```

My problem is their is no div the append it to and i cant put anything in this space to apend it to because it just needs to be the hyperlink.

```
<a class="video_click" href="video/link.flv" rel="prettyPhoto" title="Flash 10 demo"><?php echo "$fname"; ?></a>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('a.video_click').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

var test = $(this).attr('href');
alert(test);

});
```

so i grab the href their is their a way to append to say `{$name}` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Is jQuery.data() what you're looking for?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

It allows you to store arbitrary data with an element and access it later.

Comment: no still can get it to work, seeing if their is a way i can find the first href with a preg_match then replace it on click